# Unable to get results when passing a string via parameter substitution in gql query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery, string-substitution

I am able to properly pass a string variable to the gqlquery through parameter substitution, here's the code i've tried to use;

```
user_name = self.request.get('username') #retrieved from UI
p = models.UserDetails.all().filter('user_name = ', user_name).fetch(1)
```

I don't get any results and the query fails silently. But when I hard code the query like this ,

```
p = models.UserDetails.all().filter('user_name = ', "peter rice").fetch(1)
```

I get my expected resultset. I think I am passing the variable `user_name` in a wrong way, Please help me in getting my piece of code right.

Comment: P.S. I learnt that string substitution is very dangerous from Nick Johnson's posts, so I didn't give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it, I tried using this,

```
p = models.UserDetails.gql('WHERE user_name = :uname', uname = user_name).fetch(1)
```

and I got the expected resultset. I wonder why other formats have the problem in string substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `filter('user_name = ', str(user_name))` ?
I supose you are sure user_name has the expected content.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging `repr(user_name)` to verify that the string is exactly the same as what you're expecting (and that it's not unicode rather than raw). Also try logging the expression `user_name == "peter rice"`. Other than that, I can't see any reason why it would not work - there's literally no way the API can affect this, since it doesn't know where the argument you pass in comes from.